# How to do dependency injection inside ASP.NET MVC's RegisterGlobalFilters method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

I am still a bit new to using IOC containers and I'm struggling a bit. I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2 with Ninject.MVC3. I have an exception filter that basically hands off to a log service:

```
public class ExceptionLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogService _logService;

    public ExceptionLoggerFilter(ILogService logService) {
        _logService = logService;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        _logService.LogError(filterContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

I would like to use dependency injection to get the instance of the log service. However, the RegisterGlobalFilters method is static:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ExceptionLoggerFilter(???));
    }
}
```

I could use a static constructor for FilterConfig, but this just doesn't feel like a good solution.

I tried using property injection in the ExceptionLoggerFilter class, but it just didn't work (LogService was always null):

```
[Inject]
public ILogService LogService { get; set; }
```

I have read up on using the Factory pattern, but it doesn't seem to help here as I would still need to inject the Factory class into the static constructor of the FilterConfig class. I could be wrong, but this doesn't feel like the right solution either.

For now, I'm using a just-give-me-an-instance method:

```
var logService = (ILogService)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ILogService));
filters.Add(new ExceptionLoggerFilter(logService));
```

This works, but is it a good solution? Is there a better way? Is my thinking about dependency injection and IOC containers all messed up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC global filters are just a list of instances. This means that any dependencies such filter has, also become singletons. This means you should be very careful with this approach, because it is really easy to accidentally cause a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) in your application. Captive Dependencies are often hard to track and often only popup in testing or production.

Instead, you should create a proxy class that can delegate back to your container/kernel at the time the filter is used, so it can resolve the real filter on the spot. This prevents Captive Dependencies.

Such proxy can look as follows:

```cs
public class NinjectExceptionFilterProxy<TExceptionFilter> : IExceptionFilter
    where TExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly Kernel _kernel;

    public ExceptionLoggerFilter(Kernel kernel) {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        var filter = _kernel.Get<TExceptionFilter>();
        filter.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

You can register the proxy filter as follows:

```cs
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, IKernel kernel)
{
    filters.Add(new NinjectExceptionFilterProxy<ExceptionLoggerFilter>(kernel));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first register *ExceptionLoggerFilter* type as *IExceptionFilter*.
And then add the following:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        var logger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IExceptionFilter>();
        filters.Add(logger);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this is typically a bad idea, unless you know for sure that the `IExceptionFilter` registration (and all of its dependencies) are singletons, since an MVC global filter is stored globally, which means they become singletons.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by building a custom filter provider that will allow you to intercept the process where your filters are created and at this stage you can inject your dependencies.

Below is a sample with Unity, you can easily convert it to NInject

Create a class for the filter provider

```
public class UnityActionFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityActionFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }


    public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            container.BuildUp(filter.Instance.GetType(), filter.Instance);
        }

        return filters;
    }
}
```

Next, in the `FilterConfig.cs`, update the `RegisterGlobalFilters` to use the new filter provider

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            var oldProvider = FilterProviders.Providers.Single(f => f is FilterAttributeFilterProvider);
            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(oldProvider);

            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            var provider = new UnityActionFilterProvider(container);
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);

            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
```