# Dependency injection failed with IAuthorizationFilter and Simple Injector for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, simple-injector

This is very similar to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052523/dependency-injection-with-iauthorizationfilter-in-simpleinjector), but solution not works for .net core 3.1.

So, I have `IAuthorizationFilter`:

```
public class AuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;
    public AuthFilter(IUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing authZZZ: " + userService.DoSomething());
    }
}
```

and simple service

```
public interface IUserService
{
    string DoSomething();
}

class UserService : IUserService
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "Something";
    }
}
```

Registering filter and service as:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => options.Filters.Add<AuthFilter>());
...
container.Register<IUserService, UserService>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

Everything else, as in [example](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html)

And got exception while calling action:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TestSimpleInj.IUserService' while attempting to activate 'TestSimpleInj.AuthFilter'.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TypeFilterAttribute.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.ProvideFilter(FilterProviderContext context, FilterItem filterItem)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.CreateUncachedFiltersCore(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext, List<FilterItem> filterItems)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.GetAllFilters(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointFactory+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateRequestDelegate>b__0(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is actually almost given in the [q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052523/dependency-injection-with-iauthorizationfilter-in-simpleinjector) you referred to, but you just need a few minor tweaks to get it working under ASP.NET Core MVC.

You need to change the `AuthorizationFilterProxy<TFilter>` to the following:

```
public class AuthorizationFilterProxy<TFilter> : IAuthorizationFilter
    where TFilter : class, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly Container Container;

    public AuthorizationFilterProxy(Container container) =>
        this.Container = container;

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) =>
        this.Container.GetInstance<TFilter>().OnAuthorization(context);
}
```

Now you need to hook this `AuthorizationFilterProxy<TFilter>` into ASP.NET Core MVC's pipeline, which can be done as follows:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => options.Filters.Add(
    new AuthorizationFilterProxy<AuthFilter>(container)));

container.Register<AuthFilter>();
```

This, as well, is very similar to adding a global filter to ASP.NET MVC, as shown in the referenced question.

This adds the `AuthorizationFilterProxy<AuthFilter>` to the list of MVC Filters and the proxy will forward the call to Simple Injector. `AuthFilter` is now resolved from Simple Injector, and with it its `IUserService` dependency.

Comment: But now I can't have parameterless constructor on my `IAuthorizationFilter` implementation - how to use this attribute without parameters in controllers and still able to get my injected service from `OnAuthorization()`?

Comment: Why do you want to have a parameterless ctor? Btw Simple Injector should be able to create a type that has a parameterless ctor.

Comment: Because if I remove parameterless constructor, I have build error `Constructor AuthAttribute has 1 parameter but is invoked with 0 argument` while using it in Controllers. (There is no argument given to the required formal parameter `contextFactory` of `AuthAttribute.AuthAttribute(IMyContextFactory)